# Assigning new object values from another object

Tags: oop

I have an ObjectA whose property values will always be assigned to another object's (ObjectB) properites. What I have been doing is to have a service class instantiate the receiveing ObjectB and then assign the values to the new object from ObjectA. Should I instead be sending the entire objectA directly to Object B in a setter parameter or other method? What are best practices here if any?

EDIT:
In a Service class:

```
public AssignValues (objectA)
{
ObjectB objectB= new ObjectB();
objectB.prop1= ObjectA.prop1;
objectB.prop2= ObjectA.prop2;
}
```

OR

```
public AssignValues(objectA)
{
ObjectB objectB= new ObjectB();
objectB.SetValuesFromObjectA= objectA;
}
```

OR

```
public AssignValues(objectA)
{
ObjectB objectB= new ObjectB();
objectB.SetValuesFromObjectA(objectA);
}
```

OR

```
public AssignValue(objectA)
{
ObjectB objectB= new ObjectB(objectA);
}
```

Comment: Is this a question about 'constructor parameter' versus 'empty-constructor and then setter'?  Or a question about passing 'Foo(objA)' versus 'Foo(objA.Prop1, objA.Prop2, objA.Prop3)'?  Or something else?

Comment: like the second, but there is another service class that simply assigns Foo.prop1=objA.prop1, Foo.prop2=objA.prop2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer because we don't know what these classes are.  You could say, "oh, I will always pass objectA to objectB's constructor" and wind up with ...

```
public Chicken( Gorilla g )
{
  this.IsAlive = g.IsAlive;
}
```

... or something just as nonsensical.  There are so many ways to do what you want to do, the fundamental question of the "right way" depends completely what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there's an Object b constructor that takes a single parameter, an Object A:

```
 // ctor:
 ObjectB( const ObjectA& a ) {
   prop1= a.prop1;
   prop2= a.prop2;
 }

 // or ctor:
 ObjectB( const ObjectA& a ) : prop1(a.prop1), prop2(a.prop2) {
 }

 . . . 
 // use
 ObjectB b(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are of the same type, I would probably prefer to use a `Clone()` (shallow-copy) method.

If the objects are of different types, I would probably write a method that looks like your first case to keep the two types separated.  Optionally, I might do that as an extension method that takes objectA and objectB (if either one is a struct, you might have to do that by ref or return value). As I said, The main reason I would not want to use a constructor or class/instance method in this case is that you are now tying the two types together when they may not necessarily have to really know about each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered dependency injection with AutoFac?  It allows you to declare what the relationships are before actually making anything.  Then make, use, and clean-up nicely.